# When should I stop training my model?

Tags: machine-learning

I've implemented deep CNN and have this log:

```
Iter 2300, Minibatch Loss 2535.55078125, Batch Accuracy 0.800000011920929
Test accuracy = 0.7236111164093018
Iter 2400, Minibatch Loss 2402.5517578125, Batch Accuracy 0.699999988079071
Test accuracy = 0.8097222182485794
Iter 2500, Minibatch Loss 1642.6527099609375, Batch Accuracy 0.8999999761581421
Test accuracy = 0.8311110999849107
Iter 2600, Minibatch Loss 4008.334716796875, Batch Accuracy 0.8999999761581421
Test accuracy = 0.8463888929949868
Iter 2700, Minibatch Loss 2555.335205078125, Batch Accuracy 0.800000011920929
Test accuracy = 0.8077777789698706
Iter 2800, Minibatch Loss 1188.008056640625, Batch Accuracy 0.8999999761581421
Test accuracy = 0.8074999981456332
Iter 2900, Minibatch Loss 426.5060119628906, Batch Accuracy 0.8999999761581421
Test accuracy = 0.7513888908757105
Iter 3000, Minibatch Loss 5560.1845703125, Batch Accuracy 0.699999988079071
Test accuracy = 0.8733333349227907
Iter 3100, Minibatch Loss 3904.02490234375, Batch Accuracy 0.8999999761581421
Test accuracy = 0.817222214407391
Iter 3110, Minibatch Loss 9638.71875, Batch Accuracy 0.8333333134651184
Test accuracy = 0.8238888879617057
```

My question is: should I wait when training will be finished for some reason or I can stop when test accuracy is highest? It is 0.8733333349227907 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop when the **test accuracy stops increasing** or **starts decreasing**. This is called **early stopping** and is straightforward to implement. `XGBoost`, `Keras` and many libraries have this functionality as an option: https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping

Try to plot the intermediate values, it will give you important insights of the training process. Please see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#accuracy.

[image]